# How to enable word wrapping in dropdown list options in HTML for mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have one dropdown list which is created in HTML, that contain several options. That dropdown list has option which are very lengthy. So when I try to see that dropdown list in mobile, the option gets truncated. So How can I make them wrapped into next line?

Below is my code:

```
<select id="secretques" name="secretques" class="wide100">
                  <option value="">-----------------SELECT-----------</option>
                  <option value="A1">What was the first concert you attended?</option>
                  <option value="A2">What was the name of your first pet?</option>
                  <option value="A3">What street did you live on in third grade?</option>
                  <option value="A4">What school did you attend when 10 years old?</option>
                  <option value="A5">What was last name of your first grade teacher?</option>
                  <option value="A6">What is the name of city where your parents met?</option>
                  <option value="A7">What is your maternal grandmother's maiden name?</option>
                  <option value="B1>(BUSINESS CUST ONLY) WHAT IS YOUR SECRET CODE?</option>
                  <option value="Q1">What is your favorite food or drink?</option>
                  <option value="Q2">Who was your favorite teacher?</option>
                  <option value="Q3">What is the name of your favorite restaurant?</option>
                  <option value="Q4">What was the name of your childhood pet?</option>
                  <option value="Q5">What is your favorite sport or hobby?</option>
                  <option value="Q6">Where was your mother born?</option>
                  <option value="Q7">What was the name of the 1st school you went to?</option>
   </select>
```

Below is screenshot of what it is looking like:

Dropdown List
[image: Dropdown List]

Any help will be appreciated...

---

Edit:1 As suggested in comment I tried using select2 plugin.

I have downloaded "select2-4.0.3" package from github.
And imported CSS file select2.css (select2-4.0.3\select2-4.0.3\dist\css\select2.css) in my project.

Also I have imported JS file select2.js (\select2-4.0.3\select2-4.0.3\dist\js) too.
Then I put below code in my javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.select2').select2({
        dropdownAutoWidth: true
    });
});
```

Also I added "select2" class in my dropdown (html file) like below:

```
<select id="secretques" name="secretques" class="wide100 select2">
</select>
```

But none of css class of select2 is rendering. Could someone tell me why its not working with me?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. However, if you're keen to use a plugin you could use something like select2: https://select2.github.io/ in order to style things the way you want whilst still using a native select

Comment: @WimMertens: HI, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with select2 plugin. But it didnt work. I have edited my question details. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: can you add a link to your project or create a fiddle so I can see what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

add an empty optgroup

```
<optgroup label=""></optgroup>
```

which somhow causes mobile browsers to fit the text..
but you do get an emty line at the bottom of your dropdowns

so you can solve that with a  little css

```
<optgroup style="display:none" label=""></optgroup>
```

see how you go with that